# Maven/docker build for plugin server

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I have a maven build followed by a docker build to take the built artifact and place it in the docker image for execution.

It's a server component which runs many plugins.  Currently all plugins are dependencies in the server pom and end up in the final uber (spring boot) jar.

I want to change this architecture so that the plugin jars and all of their dependencies are each in their own folder on the docker image.  This is so I can classload them independently at runtime.

How can I approach my maven and docker build to accomplish this?  I am not clear how I would fetch all the dependencies of certain artifacts, and not have those artifacts included in the uber jar.

Comment: Which spring boot version do you use?

Comment: 2.4.13.  The solution need not have to do with spring boot though.

Comment: I strongly recommend to upgrade to more recent versions (because of the lack of support of such old versions) and support of more recent version related to docker images and handling of layers etc. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#container-images.efficient-images.layering Apart from that putting deps into folders in the images does not really help...also it would be helpful to give much more information what exactly you are doing etc. what kind of plugin jars??

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the solution is to take out the plugin dependencies from the server pom.xml and create an assembly.xml using the maven assembly plugin to produce a "plugins" folder which contains each plugin to be loaded at runtime.

The docker image then pulls in and installs this plugins folder.